# Apply telerik themes to WPF Dialogs

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, telerik

How can I apply telerik themes to a dialog box eg for example; MessageBox, FolderBrowserDialog. In Wpf

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the windows forms `System.Windows.Forms` dialog boxes in wpf?  If so, there is likely little hope for themeing them with Telerik WPF themes.  You *may* be able to theme them with a telerik Windows Forms theme, but I am unsure, I don't really use Forms anymore.

If however you are using the `Microsoft.Win32` namespaced dialogs, it is my understanding that they will use whatever theme is installed on the operating system by default.  The following CodeProject article shows how to dig into the API, and may be of help to you, but it doesn't specifically say how to alter the theme.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16276/Customizing-OpenFileDialog-in-NET